# remove space on same parent categories | Grouped Categories Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

i have a chart used grouped categories highcharts,  i have succesfull make a charts but i got a bit problem.

example charts:[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/)

it is possible to remove space / or change space between column which have same parent, so it will be near each other ?

in that example :

```
   apple, banana, orange   = group as fruit

   carrot, potato, tomato  = group as vegetable

   cod, salmon, tuna       = group as fish
```

i wanted :

```
 between apple, banana, orange the column is near 
 and between orange - carrot is still have space.
```

i have tried to change on style but i still can't figure it out.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these options under plotOptions inside and verticalAlign to show lables at the bottom.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      inside: true,
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.name;
      }
    },
  }
},
```

I had to change the structure of the series to make it easy to display:

```
    series: [{name:'Fruits',
      data: [{y:4, name:'Apple'}, {y:14, name:'Banana'},{y:18, name:'Orange'}]
    }, {name:'Vegetable',
      data: [{y:5, name:'Carrot'}, {y:6, name:'Potato'}, {y:5, name:'Tomato'}]
    }, {name:'Fish',
      data: [{y:14, name:'Cod'}, {y:15, name:'Salmon'} ,{y:18, name:'Tuna'}]
    }]
  });
```

example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/4capkmam/)

Answer (score 1):

i have figure it out too with diffrent style [jsfiddle][1]

```
           [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/rikad/gptrz8Lh/
```